# How to Export Database SQL using Java

Tags: java, sql, cmd, mysql

hey guys i have this code to export the database the problem it's when i execute this command it shows me that's impossible i try to execute this on CMD it works but it ask to a password i just click an enter and it export the database now i wanna add this Enter to my Code

```
public void exportData(){
String dbName = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/gmao";
String dbUser = "root"; 
String dbPass = "";
String executeCmd="";
String path="C:\test.sql";
executeCmd = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.24\\bin\\mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path;


try {
        Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);

        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if(processComplete == 0){
        System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
}
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminFW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

http://s1.postimg.org/pgdpyicrz/image.jpg this is the result

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot I can clearly see that your password is empty, thats why you get prompted for that password. Set your password:

```
String dbPass = "myUltraSecretDbPasword";
```

If you set password to your db, everything will start working without pressing `enter`. But if you are really needs to do that you can always send key to the process.

```
process.getOutputStream().write(13); // sends 'enter' code to default input of process aka process console
```

But remember to "wait" a while, until process starts and promp for password.

Comment: because my database the username is root and the password is empty

Comment: now the problem it shows me Couldn't make the BackUp

Comment: check your `processComplete` and search for details in `mysqldump `documentation. Anyway, you should also consume external process' inputstream. Process will pause otherwise. Moreover you would be able to read actual console output of `mysqldump`